# The os.date function isn't returning desired outcomes

Tags: mysql, lua, date-format, luasql, ptokax

I'm inserting a string variable to my MySQL table using this `os.date()` function call:

```
tSend["sDate"] = os.date( "%Y-%m-%d %X", Core.GetUserValue(v, 25) )
```

The table tSend is forwarded to another function which inserts it into the table.

This doesn't work as required. For eg. It'll insert **2013-01-31 12:59:59** instead of **2013-01-31 00:59:59** to the table. It happens to all the hours after the 1159 hours.

According to the [Lua PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) book,

> **`%X`** implies *time* (e.g., 23:48:10)

I can not use `NOW()` in my query as the time generated by [`Core.GetUserValue(v, 25)`](http://wiki.ptokax.ch/doku.php/scriptinghelp/ptokaxapi2#core.getuservalue_tuser_nvauleid) is a property of PtokaX and is given as **User login time in seconds from 1.1.1970**.

What can be the problem here? A simple lua code with

```
print( os.date("%Y-%m-%d %X", 1355586777) )
```

generates **2012-12-15 21:22:57** as output(where *1355586777* is the value I received from the `Core.GetUserValue` call).

I used to have `%H:%M:%S` instead of `%X` but I thought of using `%X` and it seems, I'll have to revert back.

Comment: I don't understand your problem but `%H:%M:%S` and `%X` give the same result for me (and so does `%T`).

Comment: @lhf Check my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the error in the behavior.

I think it is maybe because PtokaX is written in C and then the lua scripts are called through it. Since, the [strftime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/strftime) defines `%X` as

> writes localized time representation (locale dependent)

This causes the time output to be in 12-hour format, instead of 24 hour. I'll still have to test it after 12 PM today.

### P.S.

I don't know how to check the `locale` date format, but I'm assuming this is the only valid cause for this behavior.

---

I switched back to using `os.date( "%Y-%m-%d %X" )` in my scripts.

Comment: It says that in the PIL page you linked, too: "Note that the representations for %x, %X, and %c change according to the locale and the system."